# Replace first duplicate without regex and increment

Tags: powershell, duplicates

I have a text file and I have 3 of the same numbers somewhere in the file. I need to add incrementally to each using PowerShell.

Below is my current code.

```
$duped = Get-Content $file | sort | Get-Unique
while ($duped -ne $null) {
    $duped = Get-Content $file | sort | Get-Unique | Select -Index $dupecount
    $dupefix = $duped + $dupecount
    echo $duped
    echo $dupefix
    (Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace "$duped", "$dupefix"
    } | Set-Content $file
    echo $dupecount
    $dupecount = [int]$dupecount + [int]"1"
}
```

**Original:**

```
12345678
12345678
12345678
```

**Intended Result:**

```
123456781
123456782
123456783
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filecontent = (get-content C:\temp\pos\bart.txt )
$output = $null
[int]$increment = 1
foreach($line in $filecontent){  

    if($line -match '12345679'){            
            $line = [int]$line + $increment
            $line 
            $output +=  "$line`n"
            $increment++
    }else{       
        $output += "$line`n"
    }
}
$output | Set-Content -Path C:\temp\pos\bart.txt -Force
```

This works in my test of 5 lines being

1. a word
2. 12345679
3. a second word
4. 12345679
5. a third word

the output would be :

1. a word
2. 12345680
3. a second word
4. 12345681
5. a third word

Comment: YES! Took a  bit more modification but I got it to work with what I needed! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: No problem. Make sure to mark the post as answered. 
A tip: simplify the way you think.
Structure what you need to do, step by step. 

1. get the content
2. loop through all the lines
3. check if the line has a value, if so add to it 

thinking this way may take some time, but it will help you with your thought process. At the beginning add comment line by line (yes this isn't best practice, but it will help you)

If you would have done that, you would have for instance seen that you were getting the content of the file multiple times over

Its your FYI tho :) 
Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if i understand the question correctly:

You have a file with X-amount of lines:

1. a word
2. 12345678
3. a second word
4. 12345678
5. a third word

You want to catch each instance of 12345678 and add 1 increment to it so that it would become:

1. a word
2. 12345679
3. a second word
4. 12345679
5. a third word

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sort of. There should never be more than 10 duplicates so for every match I would have to append the numbers 0-9 at the end of the matches. So in your example 2 would be 12345670 and 4 would be 12345671.