# Pattern replace duplicates to file PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, duplicates

I had a different thread for the same scrap of code but it was a bit different of a question (the initial question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46428476/powershell-replace-first-duplicate-without-regex-and-increment/)). This one however has plagued me for hours. It seems that if there is a duplicate I cannot do a replace like

```
(Get-Content –path $origin) | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace "$value", "$newvalue"
} | Set-Content $origin
```

My issue is that regardless of what method I attempt it seems like it is near impossible to maintain the integrity of the initial source document and do a replace of duplicate values while changing them.

I have been able to get it to cycle through numbers but the amount of information available is thin surrounding modifying duplicate values in a dynamic manner. I would simply like to go through each duplicate and assign it a different number without messing with the surrounding document.

```
$duped = Get-Content $file | sort | Get-Unique
if ($duped -ne $null) {
    $filecontent = (Get-Content $file)
    $output = $null
    [int]$increment = 1
    foreach ($line in $filecontent) {
        if ($line -match $duped) {
            $dupefix = $line + $increment
            echo $dupefix
            [regex]$pattern = "$duped"
            $pattern.Replace([string]::Join("", (Get-Content $file )), "$dupefix", $dupecount) |
                Set-Content $origin
            [int]$increment++
            [int]$dupecount++
        }
    }
    $output | Set-Content -Path $file -Force 
    $output | Out-File -Append -Filepath $database -Encoding Ascii
    $duped | Out-File -Append -Filepath $database -Encoding Ascii
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking at `Select-Object -Unique`

Comment: Any chance we could get a sample of data to work with[with any sensitive information removed]? I do not want to use the data from the other question coz, well this one is about preserving the integrity of the data rather than working around a convenient set of lines. I am thinking, perhaps it is the `set-content` that messes with the integrity rather than the increments. So perhaps we should try other options.

Comment: Just really the same number multiple times in a document surrounded by other values.

Comment: Show, don't tell. Please [edit] your question and provide representative sample input and the output you want created from that input. Do you know the numbers beforehand? Or do you want to append an increment to any number that appears repeatedly? What is considered a number in your input data? Any sequence of digits regardless of context?

Comment: With this limited amount of data it's impossible to understand what you want to do. Remember my solution i posted yesterday? Remember the way it was formatted? i provided you with information on how the source data looked like, how the output would look like, ... . That's what's needed for questions like these. Just scrub it from sensitive data or make up some data.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically it was selecting every match and apply the modification to everything that matched the string I was searching for rather than going through each duplicate individually and modifying it. I was able to figure it out by using.

```
(Get-Content $origin) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "$duped", ("$duped" + [INT]$dupecount++) } | Set-Content $origin
```